# LOOKUP No Match Output

Tags: ssis, lookup

I have 5000 rows in source file with 11 columns with no duplicate rows 
& I loaded all those rows in the destination table.
Now I inserted one new record and I tried performing lookup
In the lookup I **mapped all the 11 columns** and did not pass anything
and o/p of lookup (No match output) is passed to the destination.

But my output has 5000(previously loaded) + 5001 = 10001 rows 
But **I require that 1 new record to be inserted** into destination table

Why is this happening ? Can someone tell me where I am wrong

Alternate : I tried using SCD but I couldn't figure it out which can be my business key
Columns are :  Purchased Date,City,Investor Name,Investor City, Developer Name,Square feet,Area Purchased...

Comment: You would need to show us what you are doing for us to see where you are doing it wrong.   Use screenshots of all the parts involved.

Comment: Please note the lookup component is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

The way this usually works is this:

[Load Source File/Table]  => [Lookup based on destination]

On matches (either ignore or send to update)

On no match (Insert the record)